# Click action is not working for the below code in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this code?  The map loads but a user's click action does not open up the info_window or re-center the map to the clicked point.

I want the address of a location to pop-up as an info_window whenever the user clicks on a map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Accessing arguments in UI events</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #map-canvas {
        height: 60%; width: 60%
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry&key=MY_KEY&sensor=true">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder;
            var map;
            var info_win;
            var pos;
            var marker;
        function initialize() 
        {
            google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(evt) {
                pos = evt.latLng;
                map.setCenter(pos);
            geocoder.geocode({'location': pos}, function(results, status)
                    {
                        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                            {
                                marker = new google.maps.Marker
                                ({
                                    map: map,
                                    position: pos
                                });

                                info_win = new google.maps.InfoWindow
                                ({
                                    content: results[0].formatted_address,
                                });
                                info_win.open(map,marker);  
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            alert("Could not load");
                            }
                    });
            });
         }

  </script>

</head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: You are adding the click listener to the map outside of the initialize function, so it is being added before the map is initialized:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder;
            var map;
            var info_win;
            var pos;
            var marker;
        function initialize() 
        {
            google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
            pos = map.getPosition();
            map.setCenter(pos);
            geocoder.geocode({'location': pos}, function(results, status)
                    {
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker
                        ({
                            map: map,
                            position: pos
                        });
                        info_win = new google.maps.InfoWindow
                        ({
                            content: results[0].formatted_address,
                        });
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);    
                    });
            });
         }

  </script>
```

After that you will find that a [google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) object does not have a getPosition method. It does have a getCenter method, but you probably want to use the [latLng property of the click event instead](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent).

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(evt) {
        pos = evt.latLng;
        map.setCenter(pos);
```

And fix the code that opens the info_win to open the google.maps.InfoWindow that you created:

```
    info_win = new google.maps.InfoWindow
        ({
          content: results[0].formatted_address,
        });
    info_win.open(map,marker);
```

Comment: You aren't opening it (unless you changed the code as above), you are creatig info_win, but opening infowindow.  I would think there would be an obvious javascript error.

Comment: Oh ... that!!  I fixed that.  It is not working for me.  Is it working for you?